# CO2 IR extinction coefficients near the 15 micrometer band

Tags: ir-spectroscopy, atmospheric-chemistry

I have searched multiple times for a spectrum or a table of the gaseous carbon dioxide Lambert-Beer extinction coefficients in the IR Earth thermal region.

All I found was absorption spectra.

Is this available anywhere with free access? I want it for illustrative/education purposes to make some Excel calculations.

Comment: Related: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6174548/